# Export Airflow Composer log to GCP Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-stackdriver

Is there a way to extract  all the available job log from Composer and export it into Bigquery Dataset table?

Need some advise on approaching with the design.

Requirement is to get  job info like  execution date and also if possible to add additional metadata columns into the BQ table from Composer. For eg if for loading any data from GCS to BQ I want to write the control BQ table after each job execution.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any use case for this? You cannot use logs from the GCS? When you are executing Airflow job, logs are stored on GCS. It's described in [Logs in Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/logs#logs_in)

Comment: I agree with PjoterS, in the use case you described you don't actually need the logs. Most of the relevant metadata of every dag run (including execution date) is available at the runtime of the dag. Why not just add a task that writes it into a BQ table after loading the data? Unless of course, you want to track failed tasks/dag runs etc.
If you still want the logs, as described in the link from PjoterS you can access the logs on GCS, or with Cloud Logging and create a sink to BQ (I believe it's not for free though) https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment section, `Cloud Composer` stores logs from the single `DAG's` in the environment folder inside the bucket. You can find this information in [Logs in Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/logs#logs_in).

> When you create an environment, Cloud Composer creates a Cloud Storage bucket and associates the bucket with your environment. Cloud Composer stores the logs for single DAG tasks in logs folder in the bucket.

In this documentation you can also find information about [Logging structure](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/logs#log_folder_directory_structure), [Log Types](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/logs#log_types) or [How to view Logs in Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/logs#viewing_task_logs_in):

```
$ gsutil ls -r gs://BUCKET/logs
```

This documentation also mentions [Log Retention](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/logs#log_retention). In short, logs are kept till you delete your environment or delete it manually.

As an alternative way, you could [Configuring sinks](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2) to create and manage sinks to route log entries from GCS to GBQ. You can also check [Using Cloud Storage Transfer Service to Manually Connect GCS to BigQuery](https://hevodata.com/learn/gcs-to-bigquery/#s) guide.